# Back is not working in HTML

Tags: javascript, html, canvasjs

Hi I was developing pie chart and doughnut chart. So, it was like on loading a page pie chart will open within a doughnut chart. By clicking on doughnut chart it will open another doughnut chart. And there is a link by clicking on which this goes to intial state.

Here is my fiddle -
[Fiddle link](https://jsfiddle.net/adishri22/L2y04bf8/2/)

Anyway I posting my code here-

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://canvasjs.com/assets/script/canvasjs.min.js"></script> 
<!-- <link type='text/css' rel="stylesheet" href='style.css' /> -->
<style>
#chartContainerpie{
  position: absolute;
  top: 130px;
  left: 0px;
}
#chartContainer{
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
}
#link {
visibility : hidden;
top : 0px;
left : 0px;
}
</style>
<script type="text/javascript">

window.onload = function () {
    var chart = new CanvasJS.Chart("chartContainer", {
  title: {
    text: "My First Chart in CanvasJS"
  },
  backgroundColor: "transparent",
  data: [{
    click: function(e){
       anotherchart();
   },
    // Change type to "doughnut", "line", "splineArea", etc.
    type: "doughnut",
    dataPoints: [{
      label: "apple",
      y: 10
    }, {
      label: "orange",
      y: 15
    }, {
      label: "banana",
      y: 25
    }, {
      label: "mango",
      y: 30
    }, {
      label: "grape",
      y: 28
    }]
  }]
});
chart.render();
var chart = new CanvasJS.Chart("chartContainerpie", {
    backgroundColor: "transparent",
  data: [{
    // Change type to "doughnut", "line", "splineArea", etc.
    indexLabelPlacement: "inside",
    indexLabelFontColor: "white",
    indexLabelFontSize: "14px",
    type: "pie",
    dataPoints: [{
      label: "apple",
      y: 10
    }, {
      label: "orange",
      y: 15
    }, {
      label: "banana",
      y: 25
    }, {
      label: "mango",
      y: 30
    }, {
      label: "grape",
      y: 28
    }]
  }]
});
chart.render();
}
function anotherchart () {
 document.getElementById("chartContainerpie").innerHTML = "";
  document.getElementById("chartContainer").innerHTML = "";
  document.getElementById("link").style.visibility = "visible";
 // alert(  e.dataSeries.type+ ", dataPoint { x:" + e.dataPoint.x + ", y: "+ e.dataPoint.y + " }" );
   var chart = new CanvasJS.Chart("chartContainernew", {
    backgroundColor: "transparent",
  data: [{
    // Change type to "doughnut", "line", "splineArea", etc.
    indexLabelPlacement: "inside",
    indexLabelFontColor: "white",
    indexLabelFontSize: "14px",
    type: "doughnut",
    dataPoints: [{
      label: "apple",
      y: 10
    }, {
      label: "orange",
      y: 15
    }, {
      label: "banana",
      y: 25
    }, {
      label: "mango",
      y: 30
    }, {
      label: "grape",
      y: 28
    }]
  }]
});
chart.render();
}

</script>
</head>
<body>
<div>
  <div id="chartContainerpie" style="height: 188px; width: 100%;"></div>
  <div id="chartContainer" style="height: 400px; width: 100%; "></div>
</div>
<div>
  <div id="chartContainernew" style="height: 400px; width: 100%; "></div>
  <a id="link" href="">Back</a>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Now basically my problem is very small. I need my back link to be at top-left position of the page. So, if I am moving my div tag of link above the chart, the link is not working but if I am putting it after it works. So, my question why it is not working and what can I do to make it work.

Please forgive me if it is a very simple thing.

Comment: Right click your back button and "Inspect element". You will see that another element is above your link. Learn to use your browsers debugging tools.

Comment: @Turnip yes you were correct

Comment: While `z-index` most likely fixes the issue, starting to organize elements by `z-index` is not very future proof as it can always lead to issues with new elements, taking forever to debug and find. Probably better to not have everything `position: absolute; top:0; left:0` but instead layout the elements so you have the charts below the link to begin with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is a `z-index` problem. The div->chart is over the div->link and you **can't click it**.
 Put `position:relative;z-index:100` to the div->link

Comment: thanks man...I got it now...I think there is a minimum time to accept an answer..will again try after some time

Comment: In IE, empty HTML HREF leads to directory listing. For further information, you can refer https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc848861(v=vs.85).aspx.